# How to create complex Has Many relationship in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many-through, has-many

I have 2 models:

```
Location
 + id
 + woeid

TownKeyTowns
 + id
 + town_woeid
 + key_town_woeid
```

And the relationship goes like:

1 Location has 1 key_town_woeid, which is accessible through town_woeid.

Both town_woeid and key_town_woeid are Locations related directly using the woeid column in in the Locations table.

I want to be able to say, for example:

`Location.key_town`

So far, I have the following:

```
town_city = TownKeyTown.where(:town_woeid => Location.woeid).first
key_city = Location.find(town_city.key_town_woeid)
```

Help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is anything complex, the standard Rails functionality should work for you.  You should read up about `has_many` and `belongs_to`.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to